# Python: loading data from file csv insert whole data in .db and operate on tables

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I'm learning currently a python language. Here is my question i converted .txt file to .csv then want to insert to table to database file. I have a problem with iteriation on the bottom im pasting results. How can i iterate with it? Im struggle with that few days so don't really know how to solve the problem.

txt file(few rows):

```
id,id2,album,artysta
TRMMMYQ128F932D901,SOQMMHC12AB0180CB8,Faster Pussy cat,Silent Night
TRMMMKD128F425225D,SOVFVAK12A8C1350D9,Karkkiautomaatti,Tanssi vaan
TRMMMRX128F93187D9,SOGTUKN12AB017F4F1,Hudson Mohawke,No One Could Ever
TRMMMCH128F425532C,SOBNYVR12A8C13558C,Yerba Brava,Si Vos Querés
TRMMMWA128F426B589,SOHSBXH12A8C13B0DF,Der Mystic,Tangle Of Aspens
TRMMMXN128F42936A5,SOZVAPQ12A8C13B63C,David Montgomery,"Symphony No. 1 G minor ""Sinfonie Serieuse""/Allegro con energia"
TRMMMLR128F1494097,SOQVRHI12A6D4FB2D7,Sasha / Turbulence,We Have Got Love
TRMMMBB12903CB7D21,SOEYRFT12AB018936C,Kris Kross,2 Da Beat Ch'yall
```

Python:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import sqlite3, csv

save_path = r"C:\Users\Maticz\Desktop\python"
#konwerter txt -> csv
in_file = os.path.join(save_path, "tracks.txt")
out_file = os.path.join(save_path, "Output.csv")
#df = pd.read_csv(in_file, sep="<SEP>", engine='python')
#df.to_csv(out_file, index=False)
#print(df)

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Maticz\PycharmProjects\zadanie\tracks.txt', delimiter='<SEP>',
                 engine='python', names=["id", "id2", "album", "artysta"])
print(df.head(5))
sv = df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Maticz\PycharmProjects\zadanie\tracks.csv', index = None, header=True)
con = sqlite3.connect("artists.db")
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabela (id TEXT, id2 TEXT, album TEXT, artysta TEXT);")

with open(r'C:\Users\Maticz\PycharmProjects\zadanie\tracks.csv', 'a+') as fin:
    dr = pd.read_csv(fin, delimiter=',', names=["id", "id2", "album", "artysta"]) # comma is default delimiter
    to_db = [(i['id'], i['id2'], i['album'], i['artysta']) for i in dr]
    cur.executemany("INSERT INTO tabela (id, id2, album, artysta) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);", to_db)
con.commit()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM artists")
print(cur.fetchall())
con.close()
```

Output:

```
                   id                 id2             album            artysta
0  TRMMMYQ128F932D901  SOQMMHC12AB0180CB8  Faster Pussy cat       Silent Night
1  TRMMMKD128F425225D  SOVFVAK12A8C1350D9  Karkkiautomaatti        Tanssi vaan
2  TRMMMRX128F93187D9  SOGTUKN12AB017F4F1    Hudson Mohawke  No One Could Ever
3  TRMMMCH128F425532C  SOBNYVR12A8C13558C       Yerba Brava      Si Vos Querés
4  TRMMMWA128F426B589  SOHSBXH12A8C13B0DF        Der Mystic   Tangle Of Aspens
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Maticz/PycharmProjects/zadanie/main.py", line 26, in <module>
    to_db = [(i['id'], i['id2'], i['album'], i['artysta']) for i in dr]
  File "C:/Users/Maticz/PycharmProjects/zadanie/main.py", line 26, in <listcomp>
    to_db = [(i['id'], i['id2'], i['album'], i['artysta']) for i in dr]
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Apreciate for any help thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify the operation using sqlalchemy

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
# sqlite://<nohostname>/<path>
# where <path> is relative:
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///artists.db')
df.to_sql('tabela', con = engine, if_exists = 'append', chunksize=1000)
```

this will remove the need to write to another CSV as you have the data in a pandas dataframe already. After this is done you can create your cursor to validate that the data has been written into the sqlite db file.

the statements:

```
if_exsists = 'append'
```

will force the new data to append to the table or even creates the table if it doesn't exist.

```
chunksize = 1000
```

this will write the records 1000 at a time (or all at once if less than 1000) then commit the records, saving the data to the table.

Comment: .Made it but putted more chunksize cause of too many records. I would like to print my select execute but it doesn't work there is my code : [link](http://wklejto.pl/txt781837) and here is output: [output](http://wklejto.pl/txt781838) how can i print it in the console?

Comment: @Kathelan based on your snippet, you will need to change your statements from 
`conn = engine.connect()
conn.execute("SELECT artysta, COUNT(album)  FROM tabela")
result = conn.fetchall()`
to
`result = engine.execute('SELECT artysta, COUNT(album)  FROM tabela')`

Comment: It worked. What if i would like to create 2 different tables in 1 database. The problem is that one file is around 70 mb with many record and second is almost 2,2 gb so should i skip "chunksize" ? when i create with same method second table have some erros with memory. I ll put result of compilator later cause it compile like 15 min. here is a sample of code: [link](http://wklejto.pl/txt781851) thanks for all